# Laravel artisan serve restore console output as in previous versions

Tags: laravel

For local development, I often used `error_log` with `php artisan serve` piped to `sed` (on Linux). I find it more convenient and faster than continuously opening log files. In recent versions (I'm not sure which one) of Laravel, the output (both stderr and stdout) seems filtered to me (a `WARN:` prefix is added, which overrides the output, and there are some extra line breaks). In the `artisan serve` help, I don't see options to restore the old behavior. I tried instantiating Symfony's console and use `writeln`, but it seems that the filter is applied to any output.

What can I do to restore the output as in previous versions?

I'm even fine with patching Laravel if necessary and I'm currently looking into it, if someone can point me to the commit that introduced the change I'll accept it as an answer, if there's a non-intrusive solution even better.

Answer (score 0):

The merged PR: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/43375

Patch to reverse it:

```
--- ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php.orig  2023-08-30 13:48:10.567078978 +0200
+++ ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php   2023-08-30 13:48:18.495219082 +0200
@@ -140,7 +140,10 @@
             return in_array($key, static::$passthroughVariables) ? [$key => $value] : [$key => false];
         })->all());
 
-        $process->start($this->handleProcessOutput());
+        $process->start(function ($type, $buffer) {
+            $this->output->write($buffer);
+        });
+        // $process->start($this->handleProcessOutput());
 
         return $process;
     }
```